# find a rectangle of 1s in 2d array of 1s and 0s

Tags: algorithm

I have a 2d array of objects, if the object has the property of clicked set to true, then it should be considered as "1" otherwise "0". These are blocks that are selected. I need to check if the selected boxes form a single rectangle. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 5):

**High-level:**

- Keep track of the outer-most 1s.
- Count all the 1s.
- If the count equals the area encased by the outer-most 1s, we have a rectangle.

**Pseudo-code:**

```java
left = width + 1
right = 0
top = height + 1
bottom = 0
count = 0

for x = 1 to width
for y = 1 to height
  if grid[x][y] == 1
    left   = min(left  , x)
    right  = max(right , x)
    top    = min(top   , y)
    bottom = max(bottom, y)
    count++

if count > 0 and count == (right-left+1)*(bottom-top+1)
  print "We have a rectangle!"
else
  print "We don't have a rectangle!"
```

Comment: use this, it's a lot easier than my solution.

Comment: The beauty of this solution is admirable.

Comment: Please , correct me if I am wrong but should it be min (left, Y) and max (right , Y ) instead of X ?

Comment: @Koba Fixed, thanks. (`top` and `bottom` are related to `y`, not `left` and `right`, at least according to the implementation)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like that:

- Search for the first element which is 1
- walk horizontal to the right, then down, then left, then up
- if you came back to the origin, you have a rectangle
- then ensure that all the other elements are 0.

This algorithm is O(n^2) and works if you only allow one rectangle. If you have multiple rectangles it gets complicated..

Comment: and what if the rectangle has to be filled?

Comment: @DeanHarber: then use Dukelings algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this (pseudocode):

```
// your 2d-array / matrix (N is the number of lines, M the number of columns)
m[N][M] = ...

// x coord of top left object containing 1
baseM = -1
baseFound = false
// expected width of rectangle
width = 0
widthLocked = false

// this is set to true after we started recognizing a rectangle and encounter
// a row where the object expected to be 1 in order to extend the rectangle
// is 0.
heightExceeded = false

// loop over matrix
for i = 1 to N: // lines
    // at the beginning of a line, if we already found a base, lock the width
    // (it cannot be larger than the number of 1s in the row of the base)
    if baseFound: widthLocked = true

    for j = 1 to M: // columns
        if m[i][j] == 1:
            if not baseFound:
                baseM = j, baseFound = true
                width = 1
            else:
                if j < baseM:
                    // not in rectangle in negative x direction
                    return false
                if heightExceeded:
                    // not in rectangle in y direction
                    return false
                if widthLocked:
                    // not in rectangle in positive x direction
                    if j - baseM >= width: return false
                 else:
                    width = j - baseM
        elseif baseFound:
            if widthLocked:
                // check if we left the rectangle and memorize it
                if j == baseM: heightExceeded = true
                if not heightExceeded:
                    // check if object in rectangle is 0
                    if j > baseM && j < baseM + width: return false
if baseFound:
    return true
else:
    // what is the expected result if no rectangle has been found?
    return ?
```

Runs in O(n). Beware of bugs.

Note: Most programming languages have 0-based arrays, so you may need to loop `i` from `0` to `N - 1`, same for `j`.